# change in second child css without changing first childDiv

Tags: css

i have following kind of pattern.   how to apply a css changes for second childDiv class without changing the first  childDiv class css

```
<div class="parentDiv">
<div class="childDiv">   with same class
</div>
<div class="childDiv">   with same class 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey now used to this as like

```
.childDiv:nth-of-type(2){
// css style ///
}
```

or-------------

```
   .parentDiv > .childDiv:last-child{
    // css style ///
    }
```

or------------------

if you have only two `childiv`

```
   .parentDiv > .childDiv + .childDiv{
    // css style ///
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
.childDiv:nth-child(2) {
  //css properties
}
```

Working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/pmFS5/)